# HAVING statement on a GROUP_CONCAT field returns no result while the condition exists

Tags: mysql

I'm having an issue with a HAVING clause on a string that is created by a GROUP_CONCAT statement.

Running the query:

```
SELECT row_id, GROUP_CONCAT(cell_id,'-',cell_type) AS flat_row FROM `cells`
GROUP by row_id;
```

returns the following:

```
|--------|-------------------------------------------------|
| row_id | flat_row                                        |
|--------|-------------------------------------------------|
|      1 | 1-Text,6-Text,45-Text,5-Number,37-Text,9-Number |
```

However, running

```
SELECT row_id, GROUP_CONCAT(cell_id,'-',cell_type) AS flat_row FROM `cells`
GROUP by row_id
HAVING flat_row = '1-Text,6-Text,45-Text,5-Number,37-Text,9-Number';
```

returns 0 records.

I was expecting to see the same result, does anyone know why the result is empty?
The goal here is to check whether the database contains rows that have the exact cell composition provided in the `HAVING` clause.

Comment: If I were doing this I'd explicitly order the group eg `GROUP_CONCAT(cell_id ORDER BY cell_id ASC SEPARATOR ',') ... HAVING flat_row = '1,5,6,9,37,45'` - you wouldn't want your check to fail just because the DB decided to change the order one day

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. In this case, if the order doesn't match, it's considered a different row though. So that doesn't apply to my use case.

Comment: But what I'm saying is, in general with databases, unless you mandate a particular order you get results in any order the database "feels like" at that time the query is run; for your technique to work you require the order you're hard coding so you should specify the order that the DB will groupconcat in, and hardcode the other side of the check to that order.

Comment: Actually, I see your point now. That might also affect equal rows just when the result is coming in differently. I'll consider that, thanks. But that has no relation to my question does it?

Comment: I don't know because I haven't checked/I don't have your DB with its rows stored on disk in some particular way etc, but let's say it's possible that without the HAVING the data comes in order 1,6,45,5,37,9, but adding a HAVING makes the DB plan the query differently, and suddenly the order switches to 45,37,9,6,5,1 just purely because you put a HAVING on; it's entirely possible and because you didn't mandate an order the database isn't doing anything wrong by shuffling it about.. But it could kill your technique. Even if it didn't solve the problem,I'd specify the order if I was relying on it

Comment: I tested your example but I can't reproduce the problem you describe. The query returns the row both when I use the HAVING clause and when I omit the HAVING clause. https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/68nmcSVzHnCwQ8nzDZNbZA/0

Comment: Thanks for testing that, I cleaned the sample data for this post for clarity because the types have namespaces with \ in them. It appears the problem is in my data, not in the query.
I can confirm when I test with the exact same data in this post, the result is equal in both queries in my db.

Comment: Have you tried writing `having GROUP_CONCAT(cell_id,'-',cell_type) = ...` ?

Answer (score 0):

The issue has been resolved. It was a combination of making sure that the order of the string was always the same on both sides of the comparison and properly escaping backslashes in the expected data. Thanks to Caius Jard and Bill Karwin for pointing me in the right direction!